# PIXMA TS5350 Unable to install drivers Win10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, canon-pixma

I have a Canon PIXMA TS5350 printer which is connected to my WiFi network and has been working fine.

Suddenly however, I was not able to print from my Win10 machine.

I have uninstalled all the drivers, canon SW etc.  Restarted, tried installing again just the drivers, and doing the whole set-up from the start again but it does not work.
I get an error "New Port could not be created: 001" (See screenshot)

[image]

If I try to install the printer via Windows printers, then it finds the printer but I get a "Driver not available" error.  [image]

I have uninstalled, restarted, many times, before, after trying the different methods.

Windows, can find the printer fine.  And the Canon IJ Network Connection assistant can also find it (and I can navigate to the homepage of the printer via the browser).

So it seems to be a problem locally on my machine setting up the port for it, but I can resolve it.  I find several methods online, none of which help at all.

I cannot also find how to create a ticket via Canon support (Europe) for this problem either!

Edit:  So I found that I have no ports defined in the "Printer server properties", but I also can't add any as it asks for a driver for a new "port type"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally managed to solve this myself!

After spending about 3-4 hours trying to solve this yesterday with no luck, and pulling my hair out in frustration, this morning a more specific google search for missing printer port types threw up this thread:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d7f58f6c-d87b-479b-8060-7affdf174c5f/standard-tcpip-port-missing-from-drop-down-quotcreate-a-new-port-and-add-a-new-printerquot?forum=winserverprint

Which basically says make sure that the following files are in C:\Windows\System32:

- tcpmib.dll
- tcpmon.dll
- tcpmon.ini
- tcpmonui.dll

(Which I did have)

Then add the following registry entries:

```
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port]
      “Driver”=”tcpmon.dll”

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports]
    “LprAckTimeout”=dword:000000b4
    “StatusUpdateInterval”=dword:0000000a
    “StatusUpdateEnabled”=dword:0000000
```

Then reboot.

After that, I now had TCP/IP Port type option lists in the Print Server properties dialog.

I could then run the Canon driver installation program, and this time it managed to add the port with no error, the printer is fully installed and working!

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by checking for updates and restarting the computer, as lately there have been a lot of issues with printers in recent Windows 10 updates but those have mostly been solved and if the port was in use by something else a reboot should free it

I also saw you mentioned Windows 10 S

Only certain devices are supported on Windows 10 S:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-in-s-mode-accessory-compatibility-69facb3e-8b04-b03c-9a29-de7ca31d2b37

If it is not supported you will likely need to upgrade to the full version of Windows 10:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/switching-out-of-s-mode-in-windows-4f56d9be-99ec-6983-119f-031bfb28a307

Comment: Sorry, Win10s was a typo! It is normal Win10 64. I have all the latest updates, drivers, etc. have restarted many times in-between uninstalling and installing.  And it was working fine for 12+ months.